# How to get a 2 by 1 UI alignment

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way I could attain a 2 1 alignment? Trying to achieve this via flexbox, But there doesn't seem to be an option for this directly in flexbox.

I'm looking to achieve the alignment 2 in a row and 1 to the right side aligned to the middle of the 2 as follows.

[image: Expected Result]

This is the current outcome with my CSS.

[image: Current Result]

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" 
        integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous" 
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Card App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card">
                <h4>Collections</h4>
                <p>Create Multiple Collections to have everything organized and download in any format you need.</p>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #232737;
    color: #8C90A0;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card-group {
    background-color: #1F2333;
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card {
    padding: 20px;
    gap: 10px;
    background-color: #232737;
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a div in you html and a couple of classes, and changed the css a bit:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #232737;
  color: #8C90A0;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-group {
  background-color: #1F2333;
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #232737;
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.content h4{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}

.arrow{
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" 
        integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous" 
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Card App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>Collections</h4>
                    <p>Create Multiple Collections to have everything organized and download in any format you need.</p>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right arrow"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```